# Iterate through an iterable, how to obtain previous and next value using next()?

Tags: python, iterator

```
def f(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    int_list = []
    n2 = next(i)
    while True:
        n1, n2, n3 = n2, next(i), next(i)
        print('n1', n1)
        print('n2,', n2)
        print('n3', n3)
        if n2 > n1 and n2> n3:
            int_list.append(n2)
    return int_list
```

In this case, the iterable is a list. I want to check if the integer is bigger than both the previous integer and next integer. However I can't figure out how to assign the proper values to check using the next() method

Comment: what about when the index is 0 or the end? then are you just checking one value instead of both? or does it wrap ? or do you skip looking at the first and last indices?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, you dont check the first and last indices

Comment: If you don't need top performance, the easiest way is probably to convert the iterable to a `list` or `tuple`.

Comment: The key to what is wrong with your current code is that you are calling `next()` twice during one iteration.  You need to shift your check only once during each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could do this with something like:

```
n1, n2, n3 = next(i), next(i), next(i)
while True:
    # ... do your checks
    n1, n2, n3 = n2, n3, next(i)
```

You will have to add a suitable termination condition check.

Answer (score 4):

You could create the following generator:

```
def f(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    n1, n2, n3 = next(i), next(i), next(i)
    while True:
        if n2 > max(n1, n3):
            yield n2
        n1, n2, n3 = n2, n3, next(i)
```

and then test like this:

```
>>> list(f([1, 4, 3, 8, 6]))
[4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

`collections.deque` is ideal for this sort of windowing iterator.

```
from collections import deque

def f(iterable):
    int_list = []
    it       = iter(iterable)
    n        = deque([next(it), next(it)], maxlen=3)
    for item in it:
        n.append(item)
        if n[0] < n[1] > n[2]:
            int_list.append(items[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking specifically about iterators, but you might also be interested in a solution using list comprehension:

```
def f(l):
  return [a < b > c for a,b,c in zip(l,l[1:],l[2:])]
```

For example, for `f([1,3,2,5,4])`, this returns `[True, False, True]` (omitting the first and last elements as per the question).

Comment: A bit simpler: `zip(l,l[1:],l[2:])`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `zip` could handle lists of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Start out by turning it into a `list`, then you're not stuck on a one-way street:

```
>>> a = [3,5,7,4,6,5,8]
>>> def f(iterable):
...     thelist = list(iterable)
...     return [item for num,item in enumerate(thelist[1:-1]) if max(thelist[num], thelist[num+1], thelist[num+2]) == item]
...
>>> f(a)
[7, 6]
```